# Different answer when using the 'method of undetermined coefficients' compared to Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, contour-integration

I have an ordinary differential equation:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}^2u}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + u = \mathrm{e}^{-t}\cos(t)$$

with $u(0) = u_0$ and $\dot{u}(0) = v_0$, when using the method of undetermined coefficients, I obtain the solution

$$u(t) = u_0\cos(t) + v_0\sin(t) + \frac{\cos(t) -2\sin(t)}{5e^t}$$

however using the laplace transform:

$$(p^2 + 1)(\mathcal{L}[u(t)]) - pu_0 - v_0 = \frac{p+1}{(p+1)^2 +1}$$

using partial fractions, we have,

$$ \mathcal{L}[u(t)] = \frac{3}{5(p^2+1)}-\frac{p}{5(p^2+1)}-\frac{1}{5(p^2+2p+2)} \\ \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \,+\frac{p}{(p^2+2p+2)}+\frac{pu_0}{(p^2+1)}+\frac{v_0}{(p^2+1)}$$

completing the square and with each $(p^2+1)$ in the denominator expressing $p$ in the numerator as $(p+1)-1$, we have

$$u(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\bigg[\frac{3}{5p^2 +5}-\frac{p}{5p^2 +5}-\frac{2}{5(p^2+1)+5} \\ +\frac{p+1}{5(p^2+1)+5}+\frac{pu_0}{(p^2+1)}+\frac{v_0}{(p^2+1)}\bigg]$$

which yields:

$$u(t) = \frac{-\cos(t)}{5}+ \frac{\cos(t)}{5\mathrm{e}^t} + \frac{i}{5}(\cos((1+i))t) - \cosh((1+i)t) \\+ i\sin((1+i)t)+\sinh((1+i)t)) + u_0\cos(t) + v_0\sin(t)$$

Which is not the same as the solution for the method of coefficients, can anyone explain to me why this is?

Comment: Your first solution $u(t) = u_0\cos(t) + v_0\sin(t) + \frac{\cos(t) -2\sin(t)}{5e^t}$ does not satisfy the initial condition. It gives $u(0)=u_0+1/5$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's nice to know i wasn't going insane and was just being complacent